# How to link individual Java classes to jars displayed by dependency:tree?

Tags: maven, dependencies

Is there a way to easily link a specific Java class to a jar that is listed by `mvn dependency:tree`? I tried `-X` to and `-Dverbose` to add verbosity but it didn't do it.

I have an import statement that I suspect is pulled from one jar in one version of my `pom` and from another when I change some dependency declarations in the pom because the API becomes different. But I know of no easy way to trace the imported class to a jar in the dependency tree.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? I don't know of a way to show it with existing Maven plugins, but Eclipse does it automatically: open a type and click [link with editor](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-18.htm). It'll show you the JAR it's under.

Comment: I can do it for most jars in `IntelliJ` but not for `javax..` jars, which is where my problem is

Comment: which is why I would like a simple maven way of doing it.

Comment: Please provide your pom.xml.

Comment: this question is formatted so as to be pom independent. i will not clutter the question

Answer (score 1):

To locate the maven dependency for a specific import, I usually do a `Go to -> Declaration` (<kbd>⌘B</kbd> on OSX) followed by clicking the `Scroll from Source` button in the Project tab like so:

[image]

I noticed that the first time I did this, the source for junit-3.8.1 was not present in my local maven cache due to which, Intellij IDEA decompiled the `Testcase` class. The `Scroll from Source` did not work for this de-compiled source. However after clicking the `Download Sources` and retrying the `Scroll from Source` worked fine as above.

This approach has stood me well for checking the maven dependency which is the source of *that one off* import.